# aplay produces no audible output for non-default user, but verbose status looks ok?

Tags: python, root, pulseaudio

I am writing a python script which utilizes a Raspberry PI's GPIO and thus the script must be elevated to run as sudo in order to obtain correct privileges for /dev/mem and /dev/gpiomem and access the GPIO.

However I want to play sounds from this script too, so I am now using `os.system(cmd)` method which allows Python to execute shell commands.

I am using this method to load wav files to aplay.

Python Snippit:

```
defaultUser = 'pi' #the user to run the command as
cmd = 'sudo -H -u %s bash -c \'aplay sounds/%s &\'' % (defaultUser, filename)

os.system(cmd) #now run the command as if it were typed into the shell
```

The above attempts to launch the command as the default user, and this used to work fine back when I was using alsa by it's self. however due to popping/crackling noise of the DACs turning on and off I had to switch to pulse audio and disable module-suspend-on-idle.

This lead to the above issue where I am no longer able to producing sound at all from root user.

I have tried executing these commands in the shell in an attempt to launch aplay as the default user (but none actually play any sound):

```
$ sudo -H -u pi bash -c 'aplay sounds/beep.wav &'
$ Playing WAVE 'sounds/3tone.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 44100 Hz, Mono
```

And

```
$ sudo -u pi aplay sounds/beep.wav
$ Playing WAVE 'sounds/beep.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 44100 Hz, Mono
```

Both of which produce good verbose output, just no audio.

And I do get audio if I run as non-root user (aka. pi)

What could cause pulseaudio or aplay to work for non-root user, but not when root initiates a command to run as default user?

This has trapped me in a catch 22 where I need sudo but sudo causes issues.

Thanks for any guidance!

Answer (score 1):

Pulseaudio by design only works for the logged in user.

You either need [system-wide Pulseaudio](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/SystemWide/), or you must enable one of the non-default [communication method modules](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/) for root.

Comment: I tried running `sudo systemctl --global disable pulseaudio.service pulseaudio.socket`, but was unable to get system wide working. I even added root and pi to pulse-access group. pi still plays but root still gives: "Device or resource busy" - I dont think the instructions on that site were very clear and I did not understand them. Googling system-wide pulseaudio hasn't helped any either.

Comment: Ahha, i get it now! had to run: `sudo pulseaudio --system -D` and now it works like a charm!! So simple. Of course I now need it to persist across reboots... But thanks!!